# Assigning a niladic function

Tags: apl

A non-niladic function *F* can be assigned to a variable *G* with

```
G ← F
```

However, if *F* is niladic, how do I prevent it from being evaluated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

In a way, niladic functions behave like arrays, except their value isn't determined until they are used. This also means that they exhibit value semantics rather than reference semantics. Note also, that niladic functions cannot be operands of operators, but rather their result will become the operand.

A way to circumvent both of these issues, is to wrap the niladic function in a dfn so that it takes a dummy argument (or two), and thus:

```
G←{F}
```

Comment: Interesting. I can "curry away" one dummy argument with _Bind_ with `G←⍬∘{F}`. At least `G` is not ambivalent now, only one dummy argument remains. If I try to curry away the last argument as well, as in `G←(⍬∘{F})∘⍬` then I am successful in the sense that `F` is not called/evaluated immediately. However, I do not know how I would invoke this last function `G`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It isn't evaluated because functions are only applied when given arguments, and `∘` is just a normal dyadic operator, so `⍬∘{F}∘⍬` derives a function you can assign. However, this is no more meaningful than say `⍬∘⍬` which also doesn't have any valid applications. You can still "use" it though, e.g. in `⍬∘{F}∘⍬ / 42`

Answer (score 3):

APL evaluates expressions from right to left. As soon as all arguments of a function are present the function is evaluated and the function and its arguments are replaced by the result of the evaluation.

Now consider your example G←F. If F is monadic or duadic, then F cannot be evaluated because its right argument is missing. In parser terminology the token F is shifted rather than being reduced, The first expression that can be reduced is then G←F which assigns F to G.

On the other hand, if F is niladic, then F can be (and therefore will be) evaluated immediately (with, say, result Z), so that the assignmet will be G←Z and not G←F.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do so forgive me for answering the wrong question.

To me it sounds like you want an optional right argument.
In APL2 I would do something like this:

'' ⎕EA 'G←F ra'

If ra is undefined, the Value Error will be caught and nothing happens. If you want a default value for G, make that assignment to the left of EA.

Comment: Some APL dialects allow treating a function like a sort of value, using `←` to assign such function values to a name, reminiscent of some proposals by Iverson. E.g. `Sum←{+/⍵}` (`⍵` is the right argument) and or even `Sum←+/`. They may also allow using names of functions in further function definitions, e.g. `ColSum←Sum⍉`. However, this doesn't work for niladic functions, as they immediately return a value rather than *be treated* as a value. OP is asking how to do it for niladic functions.